# How to round small decimal numbers in php

Tags: php, rounding

I have this number:

```
0.108504578471184
```

And I would like to round it keeping two decimals, I've tried using the php function [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) like this:

```
round(0.108504578471184, 2)
```

Expected result:

```
0.11
```

Actual Result:

```
0
```

Why is it giving me 0 when I've specified that I want 2 decimals?
EDIT: As noted in the comments, the problem is something else in the code.
I am selecting a xml attribute with this line

```
$selectedMpoint->xpath('/RFile/Machine/MPoint[@No="'.$MPNo.'"]/Operation[@FrqRange="'.$MPFrqRange.'"]/QParam[@Qid="1"]/@Value')[0];
```

Echoing the line:

```
echo $selectedMpoint->xpath('/RFile/Machine/MPoint[@No="'.$MPNo.'"]/Operation[@FrqRange="'.$MPFrqRange.'"]/QParam[@Qid="1"]/@Value')[0];
```

Gives me this number (same as mentioned before)

```
0.1085045784711840
```

But when I try to use round() on it it just gives me 0, I've tried putting it into a variable because I thought that it could be like the `[0], 2` at the end messing it up, but i still get 0e

```
round($selectedMpoint->xpath('/RFile/Machine/MPoint[@No="'.$MPNo.'"]/Operation[@FrqRange="'.$MPFrqRange.'"]/QParam[@Qid="1"]/@Value')[0], 2
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. https://ideone.com/exCDwR

Comment: `round(0.108504578471184, 2)` should give `0.11`, Can you share your original code ? the error should be somewhere else in your code !

Comment: Try with `number_format(0.108504578471184, 2)`

Comment: Please show your code, there is no problem in this given information.

Answer (score 1):

Although `round(0.108504578471184, 2)` produces `0.11` for me, but you can try using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
(float) number_format(0.108504578471184, 2);
```